# Ncat: Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, zabbix

На сервере настроил zabbix, и добавил скрипт оповещаний, который отправляет информацию на сокет, и на другом сервере Python программа обрабатвает.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="$1"
subj="$2"
message="$3"
to_send="{"subj": "${subj}", "message": "${message}"}"
/usr/bin/echo ${to_send} |/usr/bin/ncat ${ip} 3434
```

При запуске из терминала все ок, но при тесте из zabbix выдает Ncat: Permission denied. Пробовал ещё написать python скрипт, который делает то-же самое, но результат не поменялся (Permission denied).

Добавил пользователя zabbix в root, тоже не помогло.

Как разрещить выполение скрипта на сервере?
Спасибо

Comment: Использовать например `sudo`

Comment: Не вариант. Zabbix запускает скрипт из веб интерфейса от имени своего пользователя. Как я понимаю, этого: `zabbix:x:997:994:Zabbix Monitoring System:/var/lib/zabbix:/sbin/nologin` 

Может, есть способ в скрипт записать выпоолнение от root?
По аналогии Windows `runas /user /savecred`

Comment: а сменить владельца для скрипта не пробовали?

Comment: Да, владелец скрипта zabbix. Даже права на netcat поменял на 777
Результат тот-же

Comment: добавь `set -x` в скрипт — может он без аргументов/с не правильными аргументами вызывается... добавь strace перед netcat'ом — посмотри до чего именно у него прав не хватает... ЗЫ: к делу скорей всего не относится, но в `to_send` подозрительно много кавычек...

Comment: «`Может, есть способ в скрипт записать выпоолнение от root?`» — это и есть «`sudo`»... но для беспарольного запуска конкретного скрипта понадобится настройка...

Comment: А в чем тут проблема ? Если отправляет инфо на сокет, так добавьте на сокет права для zabbix. Либо если не хотите, можете использовать sudo

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл `/etc/sudoers.d/zabbix`
И добавьте в него следующие стройки:

```
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty
Cmnd_Alias ZABBIX_CMD = /usr/bin/ncat
zabbix   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: ZABBIX_CMD
```

Comment: Не сработало, к сожалению

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, `sudo` надо перезапустить. `service sudo restart`

Answer (score 0):

also it could be selinux. Check by disabling it:

```
setenforce 0 && sudo sed -i 's/^SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config
```

it helped me.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык